# How to clean various log files in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am using centos and cpanel for magento 2.4.2 installation. I noticed that there is huge files in the directory public_htmls/var/log/bak. is there anyone who could guide me how to:

1. Clean the various log files manually using CLI commands for centos. I have seen some sudo commands for that but not working not centos.
2. [image]tell me whats that folder bak for?

Comment: the best way to manage logs is with logrotate, it will compress logs and keep only a certain history (depends on configuration). Take a look here: https://magenaut.com/magento-2-log-rotation-with-logrotate/

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command in the directory where your Magento is installed,

`rm -rf var/log/*`

This will fix your problem.